# Overflow:scroll doesn't work when I add content to div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a div on my page with the following styles and no content to begin with:

```
                        #chatwindow {
                                width: 500px;
                                height: 50px;
                                overflow-y: scroll;
                                margin: 5px auto;
                                background: white;
                                border: 1px solid black;
                        }
```

Now, I have a simple Javascript function which adds new lines to the div:

```
function updateChat(response) {
                        $('#chatwindow').append('<p>' + response + '</p>');
                        $("#chatwindow").attr({ scrollTop: $("#chatwindow").attr("scrollHeight") });
                }
```

It's supposed to add a line to the div and scroll to the top. However, after the content within the div becomes too large for the div, the overflow doesn't scroll - it remains invisible beyond the lower border of the div. What do I do (preferably with CSS alone) to make the div's scrollbar show up when the content becomes too large?

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vmba8/)

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/scrolltop/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`scrollTop` is not an HTML attribute, it is however a [jQuery method](http://api.jquery.com/scrolltop/), among other things ?

```
$("#chatwindow").scrollTop( $("#chatwindow").attr("scrollHeight") );
```

note that `scrollHeight` is not an HTML attribute either, unless you added it for some reason, hard to tell without the markup, but you're probably looking for the native scrollHeight property

```
$("#chatwindow").scrollTop( $("#chatwindow").prop("scrollHeight") );
```

Comment: @BlackSheep - was just adding that, but didn't think about prop(), which would be more jQuery'ish. Edited.

Comment: Alright, I see what you mean now. Sorry, I have removed my comment, I didn't think anyone had had a chance to read it. I will accept this answer in a few minutes.